# Implications of the form $A \vee B \implies C$: what to do about the disjunction?

Tags: logic

I am aware that $A \vee B \implies C$ is logically equivalent to $(A \implies C) \wedge (B \implies C)$.  This is what is causing me an issue. If I am proving the original disjunction, is it sufficient to consider a case when $A$ alone is true, and show that the implication is true? That would mean that the disjunction is true, so hypothesis is true. Or do I need to consider the entirety of the conjunction in order to prove it, since if there are cases in which $B$ is false but $C$ is true the conjunction would also be false.

My issue is that in the case where $B$ is false but $C$ is true, the disjunction hypothesis may be true (depending on $A$), while the entire conjunction is false, so it appears as though the two are not logically equivalent.

Comment: The hypothesis is true when $A\vee B$ is true. $A\vee B$ is true when $A$ is true or $B$ is true. $B$ might be true when $A$ is not true so just considering the case $A$ true is insufficient.

Comment: Ah, I understand.  That would be a good answer, and if you post it I will accept it

Comment: Can you tell us what you mean by $A\implies C\wedge B\implies C$? Note that $(p\implies q)\implies r$ and $p\implies(q\implies r)$ are not equivalent (take $p=r=0$) so the meaning of a cascaded implication without brackets is unclear.

Comment: Yes, good catch, I've added brackets to clarify

Comment: Ah, now I see it is not a cascaded implication at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis is true when $A\vee B$ is true. $A\vee B$ is true when $A$ is true or $B$ is true. $B$ might be true when $A$ is not true, making the hypothesis true when $A$ is false. So just considering the case $A$ true is insufficient. For example, $x=1\vee x=2$ is true when $x=1$ or $x=2$.

When $B$ is false and $C$ is true, $B\implies C$ is true (remember that the only contradiction to $B\implies C$ is when $B$ is true and $C$ is false). The disjunction hypothesis is true iff $A$ is true. Then $A\implies C$ is true so the conjunction is also true. Indeed, the two statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

> My issue is that in the case where B is false but C is true, the disjunction hypothesis may be true (depending on A), while the entire conjunction is false, so it appears as though the two are not logically equivalent.

That is not so.

*When $C$ is true*, any conditional of the form $\phi\to C$ is true, whatever $\phi$ may be.   Thus too is any statement of the form $(\phi\to C)\leftrightarrow((\psi\to C)\wedge(\chi\to C))$, including:$$((A\vee B)\to C)\leftrightarrow((A\to C)\wedge (B\to C))$$

---

*When $B$ is false*, then any conditional of the form $B\to\phi$ is true. So any $\psi$ is equivalent to $\psi\wedge(B\to\phi)$. Likewise any $\chi\vee B$ is equivalent to $\chi$.

Thus $\neg B$ entails that: $(A\vee B)\to C$ is equivalent to $A\to C$ and this is equivalent to $(A\to C)\wedge (B\to C)$.